# Angular Material doesn't render properly after updating project

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have just updated Angular project from Angular 15 to Angular 16, and everything seems to work properly, except that Material components render poorly:

(Like outlined form fields on the image, for example)
[How outlined form fields render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV3UW.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I tried to update Material version, and also tried to update all the outdated packages, but it did not solve the problem. Also, I've double-checked the compatibility with my Node, TypeScript and Angular CLI, and everything seems to be fine.